Determine the values of k for which the equation $\dfrac{x^2+x+2}{3x+1}=k$ has both roots real.
My attempt: First i simplified this to a quadratic:
$$\dfrac{x^2+x+2}{3x+1}=k$$  can also be written as, $$x^2+x+2=3kx+k \implies x^2+x+2-3kx-k=0$$
now taking $x$ common we have, $$x^2 +(1-3k)x+(2-k)=0$$
Now I know that for the equation to have both roots real the Discriminant must be greater than zero but I can only solve a quadratic equation using the quadratic formula if the RHS is equal to $0$ so I thought maybe I can write the discriminant equal to 1 and then bring 1 to the LHS but then there would be many possibilities, I mean I can put 2 and 3 and nay positive integer on the RHS and then solve for it, like this: $D=1 $ or $D=2$ and so on. so what shall I do. One more thing I am confused about is that the question asks for both the roots to be real so can it be like that both the roots be coincident and real, which can be done if $D=0$ ?
Source: Challenge and thrills of Pre-College Mathematics

This: $$x^2+x+2=3kx+k=x^2+x+2-3kx-k$$ is false. $$\ $$ What you meant here should be written as $$x^2+x+2=3kx+k$$ so $$x^2+x+2-3kx-k=0$$

Downvoted because OP wrote a statement which he did not justify (and is clearly false), i.e. what CiaPan points out is so important that for me it warrants a downvote. OP - you must avoid doing this to succeed in high-school algebra and maths in general.

@CiaPan Thanks for pointing that out! I realize my mistake and will try to be more careful next time

@AdamRubinson I appreciate the feedback. I understand now that I should be more careful in presenting logical steps and avoid misusing the equality sign for simplification. I'll ensure to improve this in my future questions.

We have $$x^2 +(1-3k)x+(2-k)=0$$ For both roots real, we must have $D\ge0$ $$\implies (1-3k)^2-4(2-k)\ge0$$ $$\implies 9k^2-2k-7\ge0$$ $$\implies (k-1)\left(k+\frac79\right)\ge0$$ $$\implies \boxed
{\color{red}{k\in\left(-\infty,-\frac79\right] \cup [1,\infty)}}$$

I've swapped the intervals in your final result so that they're ordered by their ends' values.

I would appreciate if you could also address the misconceptions/questions that OP has in their writeup? I know it's not necessary to answer the question stated in the title, but that is what OP is posting about. IE " I though maybe I can write the discriminant equal to 1 and then bring 1 to the LHS but then there would be many possibilities" and "One more thing I am confused about is that the question asks for both the roots to be real so can it be like that both the roots be coincident and real, which can be done if $D=0$".

@CalvinLin op knows that we must have D>=0 but maybe he hasnt worked with inequalities yet...thats why he wanted to find k by equating D to 1,2,3... and so on
